# jQuery Mobile page not scrolling in Xperia

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, scroll

I have developed a web app with jQuery Mobile that works fine in most phones I've tested it on, but recently found out that on SonyEricsson Xperia the pages won't scroll!

Is there anyone here who has come across scrolling problems on any platform with jQuery Mobile apps and knows what causes it and possibly what to do about it?

If I download Opera Mobile browser on the Xperia it works fine, so it only seems to have to do with the default browser (which I don't know what it is, but I assume Google's stock browser...)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when my JQM web application wouldnt scroll on Xperia.
Firstly I would recommend testing whether you can scroll over content on this page: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-performance.html

In my case I could scroll over the content provided via the link above, so I realised it was a local problem. After some research I found out that I had `overflow:hidden` property attached to my `html,body` via one of my css files.